# PHP control HTML Layout

Tags: php, html

Need a little help with a solution for this problem. I have a list of services that is generated as such:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach( $entries as $s ) : ?>
    <?php require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/_index_DisplayService.php' ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**_index_DisplayService.php**

```
<div class="grid-4">
    <div id="service-mobile-dev" class="service">   
        <div class="service-icon">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is a grid-12 layout, so I need 3, grid-4 per row then new row. I think that a solution starts with moving the `<div class="row">` below `<?php foreach( $entries as $s ) : ?>` looking something like this:

```
<?php foreach( $entries as $s ) : ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/_index_DisplayService.php' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This of course kicks everything to a single row. How do I go about generating 3 grid-4's per row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `index => value` properties in a `foreach` (or replace it entirely with a `for` loop) and run a modulo on the index to insert the row div conditionally. Assuming `$entries` is an `array`.

```
<?php
    foreach ($entries as $key => $value) :
        
        // Close the "previous" row tag before beginning the next row
        // Obviously we should not start with a closing tag ($key > 0)
        if ($key > 0 && $key%3 == 0) {
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        
        // Start a new row
        if ($key%3 == 0) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php
        }
        
        // Insert the "grid-4" elements
        require dirname(__FILE__) . '/_index_DisplayService.php';

    endforeach;
    
    // If there were any entries then we have a row which hasn't been closed yet.
    // Close it.
    if (count($entries) > 0) {
        ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: cool thanks fo the help on this. Haven't quite got it working yet. Here is link to issue if it helps in determining where I am going wrong. http://www.lucas.photoappoint.com/appointment/

Comment: @Bungdaddy View your source in the browser dude (Ctrl+U in Firefox). Your HTML is the problem in the link you provided. You've closed an extra div after closing "grid-4". `</div><!-- /grid-4-->
     </div>`. Remove that second `</div>` and it should (ideally) start working for you.

Comment: @Bungdaddy Shoot I found an issue with the solution. Updating it now.

Comment: Super solid answer! Was cracking my skull on that </div> -- thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$entries` is an indexed array, `$ind%3` will be 0 when `$ind` is 0,3,6 and 9.

```
<?php foreach( $entries as $ind=>$s ) : ?>
    <?if($ind%3==0){?><div class="row"><?}?>
        <?php require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/_index_DisplayService.php' ); ?>
    <?if($ind%3==0){?></div><?}?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to set a counter. I added a fake array that represent your entries, so you can test it as is. As I wrote this, it looks like some others posted some really great answers as well. Good luck!

```
    $entries = array(
        'entry-one',
        'entry-two',
        'entry-three',
        'entry-four',
        'entry-five',
        'entry-six'
);

$counter = 0;
foreach( $entries as $s ) {
    if( $counter > 2 ) {$counter = 0;}
    if( $counter === 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="row">' ;
    }

    echo '
    <div class="grid-4">
        <div id="service-mobile-dev" class="service">   
            <div class="service-icon">
                <i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
                . $s .'
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    if( $counter === 2) {
        echo "</div>";
    }
    $counter++;
}
```